# Android action bar not displaying on older Android versions

Tags: android

I have an action bar in my activity, declared as following:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger);
```

and my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.wega.mcfc.DashboardActivity" >

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I just recently tried my app on an older Android version (4 instead of 6) and the toolbar is not showing anymore, is there something else I'm supposed to do for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Is it support toolbar layout? i.e.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout


android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
...
...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    ...
... />
```

Comment: Yes it's a android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in a RelativeLayout in a android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

Comment: I don't have a toolbar.xml, I edited my question to add the xml of my activity.